# Swift/iOS - How to compress audio so that it can be streamed to another device, then decompress and play the same audio

Tags: ios, swift, type-conversion, compression

I've been using the following methods to convert an AVAudioPCMBuffer to [UInt8] and then [UInt8] back to an AVAudioPCMBuffer. The problem is that every single conversion is a total of 17640 bytes, which to stream over MultipeerConnectivity is a lot. In fact, I think my stream ends up reading data slower than data is coming in, since if I end the stream on one device I can see that the other continues to read data until it realizes that the stream has ended.

Here is my conversion of AVAudioPCMBuffer to [UInt8]. Credit for this answer goes to [Rhythmic Fistman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22147/rhythmic-fistman) from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39505888/trying-to-stream-audio-from-microphone-to-another-phone-via-multipeer-connectivi).

```
func audioBufferToBytes(audioBuffer: AVAudioPCMBuffer) -> [UInt8] {
    let srcLeft = audioBuffer.floatChannelData![0]
    let bytesPerFrame = audioBuffer.format.streamDescription.pointee.mBytesPerFrame
    let numBytes = Int(bytesPerFrame * audioBuffer.frameLength)

    // initialize bytes by 0 
    var audioByteArray = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: numBytes)

    srcLeft.withMemoryRebound(to: UInt8.self, capacity: numBytes) { srcByteData in
        audioByteArray.withUnsafeMutableBufferPointer {
            $0.baseAddress!.initialize(from: srcByteData, count: numBytes)
        }
    }

    return audioByteArray
}
```

And here is [UInt8] to AVAudioPCMBuffer

```
func bytesToAudioBuffer(_ buf: [UInt8]) -> AVAudioPCMBuffer {

    let fmt = AVAudioFormat(commonFormat: .pcmFormatFloat32, sampleRate: 8000, channels: 1, interleaved: false)
    let frameLength = UInt32(buf.count) / fmt.streamDescription.pointee.mBytesPerFrame

    let audioBuffer = AVAudioPCMBuffer(pcmFormat: fmt, frameCapacity: frameLength)
    audioBuffer.frameLength = frameLength

    let dstLeft = audioBuffer.floatChannelData![0]

    buf.withUnsafeBufferPointer {
        let src = UnsafeRawPointer($0.baseAddress!).bindMemory(to: Float.self, capacity: Int(frameLength))
        dstLeft.initialize(from: src, count: Int(frameLength))
    }

    return audioBuffer
}
```

Can anyone help me compress this data so that it is easier to send over a stream, and then decompress it so it can be played?

Comment: Facing the same problem now, did you find a solution to this? And what did you end up using?